# Starting xbmc fails with TV connected, "unable to create GUI"

Tags: linux, tv, kodi

I got an `Banana Pi` with `Bananian` running on it. I installed `xbmc` on it. When I connect my `Banana Pi` to my TV with a HDMI cable it shows an `TTY` as expected. When I try to run `xinit /usr/bin/xbmc --standalone` from a `PuTTY` session I get this error:

```
ERROR: Unable to create GUI. Exiting
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Crash report:

```
############## XBMC CRASH LOG ###############

################ SYSTEM INFO ################
 Date: Wed Sep  9 13:31:03 CEST 2015
 XBMC Options:
 Arch: armv7l
 Kernel: Linux 3.4.108-bananian #2 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 13 06:08:25 UTC 2015
 Release: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
############## END SYSTEM INFO ##############

############### STACK TRACE #################
gdb not installed, can't get stack trace.
############# END STACK TRACE ###############

################# LOG FILE ##################

13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to: special://masterprofile/
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Starting XBMC from Debian (13.2 Debian package version:2:13.2+dfsg1-4). Platform: ARM (Thumb) Linux 32-bit
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Using Debug XBMC x32 build, compiled Nov  8 2014 by GCC 4.9.2 for ARM (Thumb) Linux 32-bit 3.16.5
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Running on Linux 32-bit (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie), 3.4.108-bananian armv7l)
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Host CPU: ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l), 2 cores available
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: ARM Features: Neon enabled
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/share/xbmc
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/xbmc
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /root/.xbmc/userdata
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to: /root/.xbmc
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: special://temp/ is mapped to: /root/.xbmc/temp
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: The executable running is: /usr/lib/xbmc/xbmc.bin
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Local hostname: peter
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Log File is located: /root/.xbmc/temp/xbmc.log
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: ConsoleKit.Manager: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit was not provided by any .service files
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: Previous line repeats 1 times.
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: DeviceKit.Power: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.DeviceKit.Disks was not provided by any .service files
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: Selected UPower as PowerSyscall
13:31:02 T:3000336384   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs - No such property CanSuspend
13:31:02 T:3000336384   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs - No such property CanHibernate
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: load settings...
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CSettings: loaded settings definition from special://xbmc/system/settings/settings.xml
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CSettings: loaded settings definition from special://xbmc/system/settings/linux.xml
13:31:02 T:3000336384   ERROR: PulseAudio: Failed to connect context
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: PulseAudio might not be running. Context was not created.
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround71" for playback
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround51" for playback
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround71" for playback
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround40" for playback
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround51" for playback
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "surround71" for playback
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Found 1 Lists of Devices
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Enumerated ALSA devices:
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:     Device 1
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : @
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Default (sunxi-CODEC sunxi PCM)
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra:
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,96000,192000
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S16LE
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml)
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://masterprofile/advancedsettings.xml)
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Default DVD Player: dvdplayer
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Default Video Player: dvdplayer
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Default Audio Player: paplayer
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Disabled debug logging due to GUI setting. Level 0.
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Log level changed to 0
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://xbmc/system/playercorefactory.xml.
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerCoreConfig::<ctor>: created player DVDPlayer for core 1
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerCoreConfig::<ctor>: created player oldmplayercore for core 1
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerCoreConfig::<ctor>: created player PAPlayer for core 3
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: system rules
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: rtv
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: hdhomerun/myth/mms/udp
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: lastfm/shout
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: rtmp
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: rtsp
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: streams
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: aacp/sdp
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: mp2
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: dvd
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: dvdimage
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: sdp/asf
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: nsv
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPlayerSelectionRule::Initialize: creating rule: radio
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Loaded playercorefactory configuration
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml.
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml does not exist. Skipping.
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: creating subdirectories
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: userdata folder: special://masterprofile/
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: recording folder:
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: screenshots folder:
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: load language info file: special://xbmc/language/English/langinfo.xml
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: trying to set locale to en_US.UTF-8
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: global locale set to en_US.UTF-8
13:31:02 T:3000336384    INFO: load English language file, from path: special://xbmc/language/
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: POParser: loaded 3162 strings from file /usr/share/xbmc/language/English/strings.po
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: DllAvUtilBase: Using libavutil system library
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: DllAvCodec: Using libavcodec system library
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: DllAvFormat: Using libavformat system library
13:31:02 T:2931606432  NOTICE: Thread ActiveAE start, auto delete: false
13:31:02 T:2921329568  NOTICE: Thread AESink start, auto delete: false
13:31:02 T:2921329568    INFO: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - initialize sink
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - trying to open device ALSA:@
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Input Channel Count: 2 Output Channel Count: 2
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Requested Layout: FL,FR
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Got Layout: FL,FR
13:31:02 T:2921329568    INFO: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - Attempting to open device "@"
13:31:02 T:2921329568    INFO: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - Opened device "sysdefault"
13:31:02 T:2921329568    INFO: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Your hardware does not support AE_FMT_FLOAT, trying other formats
13:31:02 T:2921329568    INFO: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Using data format AE_FMT_S16NE
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Request: periodSize 2048, bufferSize 8192
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Got: periodSize 2048, bufferSize 8192
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::InitializeHW - Setting timeout to 186 ms
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Input Channel Count: 2 Output Channel Count: 2
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Requested Layout: FL,FR
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CAESinkALSA::GetChannelLayout - Got Layout: FL,FR
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - ALSA Initialized:
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Output Device : Default (sunxi-CODEC sunxi PCM)
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Sample Rate   : 44100
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Sample Format : AE_FMT_S16NE
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Channel Count : 2
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Channel Layout: FL,FR
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Frames        : 2048
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Frame Samples : 4096
13:31:02 T:2921329568   DEBUG:   Frame Size    : 4
13:31:02 T:2931606432   DEBUG: DllAvUtilBase: Using libavutil system library
13:31:02 T:2931606432   DEBUG: DllAvFormat: Using libswresample system library
13:31:02 T:3000336384  NOTICE: Running database version Addons16
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: SECTION:LoadDLL(special://xbmcbin/system/libcpluff-arm.so)
13:31:02 T:3000336384   DEBUG: Loading: /usr/lib/xbmc/system/libcpluff-arm.so
13:31:03 T:3000336384    INFO: ADDON: cpluff: 'Could not read plug-in directory /usr/lib/xbmc/addons: No such file or directory'
13:31:03 T:3000336384  NOTICE: ADDONS: Using repository repository.xbmc.org
13:31:03 T:3000336384    INFO: LIRC Initialize: using: /dev/lircd
13:31:03 T:3000336384    INFO: LIRC Initialize: connect failed: No such file or directory
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: Failed to connect to LIRC. Retry in 10s.
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: LoadMappings - loaded node "Motorola Nyxboard Hybrid"
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: LoadMappings - loaded node "CEC Adapter"
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: LoadMappings - loaded node "Pulse-Eight CEC Adapter"
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: LoadMappings - loaded node "iMON HID device"
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: CPeripheralBusUSB - initialised udev monitor
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: SECTION:LoadDLL(libcec.so.2)
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: Loading: libcec.so.2
13:31:03 T:3000336384   ERROR: Unable to load libcec.so.2, reason: libcec.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: Dll libcec.so.2 was not found in path
13:31:03 T:3000336384   ERROR: Initialise - failed to initialise bus cec
13:31:03 T:2910843808  NOTICE: Thread PeripBusUSBUdev start, auto delete: false
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: UDisks: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.UDisks was not provided by any .service files
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: DeviceKit.Disks: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown - The name org.freedesktop.DeviceKit.Disks was not provided by any .service files
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: Selected UDev as storage provider
13:31:03 T:3000336384   ERROR: InitWindowSystem: Could not initialize
13:31:03 T:3000336384   FATAL: CApplication::Create: Unable to init windowing system
13:31:03 T:3000336384   DEBUG: PVRManager - destroyed
```

What is causing this error and how can I fix this?

By the way, I am able to run `startxfce4` and get the `XFCE` GUI on my TV.

**Update:** 
I tried to run `xbmc` inside `KDE` and `Xfce` and I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't see anything in the log about displays / screens being detected- can you try it plugged into a monitor instead of a TV? What version of xbmc/kodi?

Comment: How did you obtain your copy of Kodi?

Comment: @DanielB I installed it with `apt-get install xbmc`

Answer (score 1):

You have the following line:

> 13:31:03 T:3000336384   FATAL: CApplication::Create: Unable to init windowing system

This seems to suggest that the standalone Xbmc call is unable to start a graphical environment.

You may try the following alternative path:

1. Start Xfce4;
2. create a launch icon for Xbmc on your desktop, or on your panel.
3. start Xbmc now from the launch icon, *i.e.* with the graphical environment already started.

This is what I do under Debian and KDE (not a RPI, though). And, just for the fun of it, I found that [CuBoxTV](http://cuboxtv.com/), with Xbmc/Kodi pre-installed, is a much superior alternative, and worth every penny it costs more than an RPI.

Edit:

if you want to execute `Xbmc` automatically when you activate Xfce4, just place an executable file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d` called `99zz` so that it executes last, with the following content:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  /usr/bin/xbmc &
```

and you are done.

Comment: I created the launch icon but when I start it (double click or right click -> execute) nothing happens even though it seems that the process is running. (I find it with `htop`). Is `Exec=xinit /usr/bin/xbmc --standalone` right for the desktop file?

Comment: @Peter I use simply `/usr/bin/xbmc` to start the program.  Please also see my edit.

Comment: This won't open the `xbmc` GUI for me. Do I have to do anything else to see the `xbmc` GUI?

Comment: @Peter It does open the Xbmc on my two systems. Then I cannot help you there, sorry.

Comment: I still get the error `FATAL: CApplication::Create: Unable to init windowing system`. I think thats why I can't see anything.